# MVC why is UpdateModel sometimes used in Edit and sometimes not

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and I've been looking through a bunch of examples.

For the `HttpPost` on some edits they call `UpdateModel(entity)`.

In other examples such as:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-5

`UpdateModel(entity)` isn't called at all.

What's the point of calling this function when it appear unneccessary in MVCMusicStore?

Apparently it " Updates the specified model instance using values from the controller's current value provider."

However I've found from the MVCMusicStore example the updated values are already posted through?

Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Usually it's called on HttpPost Actions and not called on HttpGet(unmarked) Actions and  `http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-5` would call the Get Action and that's why there is no `UpdateModel()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think ModelBinding is only introduced in newest version of asp.net mvc (newest version is 3). it was present at least in v-2 so far as i can tell. when you call the updatemodel you call Modelbinding explicitly. when you receive at as action method parameter Modelbinder is called implicitly.
In Edit scenario updateModel is used when we fetch original entity from db and tell controller to update it using UpdateModel like

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var entity = db.GetEntity(id);
   UpdateModel(entity);
   db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Other scenario is when you are not fetching db entity but ModelBinder gives you an entity created from form fields etc. and you tell you db that object is already there and it has been modified outside the db and you better sync with it like in [MusicStore](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-5) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no reason for you to use UpdateModel in the newer version of ASP.NET MVC

Originally it was provided because when you posted your data back to the action on your controller, a FormsCollection would be passed in to to the action and then a call to `UpdateModel(entity)` would be required.

However in newer versions of ASP.NET MVC the concept of [ModelBinding](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx) has been introduced which will allow your actions to define a .net object to be passed in to your action methods and the model binder will take care of "binding" the values to the model.

To be completely honest, I'm not sure why they don't just deprecate the `UpdateModel()` method because AFAIK it's completely redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UpdateModel` for `PATCH` semantics. From [RFC5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789):

> The PATCH method requests that a set of changes described in the
> request entity be applied to the resource identified by the
> Request-URI.

This means you are making modifications to an existing resource (e.g. from the database).

Use *the object as action method parameter* for `PUT` semantics.

> The difference between the PUT and PATCH requests is reflected in the
> way the server processes the enclosed entity to modify the resource
> identified by the Request-URI.  In a PUT request, the enclosed entity
> is considered to be a modified version of the resource stored on the
> origin server, and the client is requesting that the stored version be
> replaced.

In practice, there's not much difference if the request contains values for all of the resource members. But if the request only contains values for a subset of the resource members, in `PATCH` the other members are left unmodified, and in `PUT` are set to their default value (usually NULL).